# Jomla 3.4 Article option not working for individual article

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I installed Joomla 3.4 on localhost, everything properly set up.

But I have an issue: the individual **articles** option is not working, I can only change global articles setting .

Article settings (not global):
[image]

Result:
[image]

I already set **show author** to hide , but author is still displayed on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of Joomla can be a bit confusing. But article settings can also be controlled through the *menu item*, and these settings will override both Global settings and Article settings.

Go to Menus -> *your menu* and locate the menu item used to display your page. From the **Options** tab, configure everything as required. Try to keep as many settings as possible set to <kbd>Use Global</kbd> (and configure the Global settings as required), this makes it easier to maintain your site, and you won't have to change settings for each menu item.

[image: Menu item settings]